# How can I get a C function crash in iOS？

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, crash

We usually use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` or `signal` to catch an Objective-C crash, but I find it can't catch a C function crash. So how can I catch a C function crash?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what exactly you're trying to accomplish? For example: what specific kind of crash are you expecting to catch? Are you expecting to recover from the crash, or is this just for crash reporting?

Comment: For anybody to be able to help you will need to provide more details, you can edit your question to do that (or delete this one and start a new one). Consider adding code fragments showing how you use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` and `signal()`, make it clear what signals you are catching. Provide details on the actual "C function" crash you are getting that you can't catch. Say what happens when you run your code under the debugger, does it also fail to catch the crash?  Etc. With those details someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Intercepting crashing events on Apple platforms is not straight-forward. `signal` can be used to capture many event types, but there are some kinds of terminations that will be missed when using just signals. The mach exception facility (non to be confused with runtime exceptions) can be used to capture more types of events. Technically, `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` does not capture crashes, just the details of uncaught Objective-C exceptions. It does not capture uncaught C++ exceptions, even though under the hood ObjC exceptions are built on top of C++.

Annoyingly, you really cannot rely on just one system. I've found the POSIX signal facilities on Apple platforms to be problematic. But, because of some limitations in how mach exceptions work, using both will get you the most coverage.

Now, C functions are not really special or distinct from ObjC methods. If you are missing a crash, it's likely due to the nature of the crash itself, or how you are instrumenting your process. I'd need to see details about both to give you better information. If you can, please update your question with more details.

You might also be interested in an open source project I work on that is specifically designed to be the core of a crash reporting system. Feel free to consult the code and/or try it out. https://github.com/ChimeHQ/Impact